# xamarin.android: SQLiteAsync not working

Tags: asynchronous, sqlite, xamarin.android

I have a sqlite database file containing list of words. My goal is to show the records that match with what user has provided in the textview1 and populate listview1 accordingly;

```
var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);

textview1.TextChanged += delegate
            {
                var Records = conn.Table<Entries>().Where(a => a.Entry.StartsWith(textview1.Text)).Take(10);

                List<string> lst = new List<string>();

                Records.ToListAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    foreach (Entries record in t.Result)
                    {
                        lst.Add(record.Entry);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<string> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, lst);
                    listView1.Adapter = myArrayAdapter;
                });
            };
```

The non Async methods work just fine but the Async version is not. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add async keyword before your function name in which you have written that code.
For Example-

```
public async void Register()
{
   //Your Code for calling async method.
   //Sample code- 
   HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
   HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(URL);
}
```